# Bind click event to Google Custom Search results

Tags: jquery, google-custom-search

I am using Google Custom Search to get the results of a search query. The results are coming fine. I now need to capture the click event on the results generated. 
I have tried the following so far:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        window.__gcse = {
            callback: myCallback
        };

        function myCallback() {
            $('input.gsc-input').keyup(function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) { console.log('enter pressed'); } });
            $('input.gsc-search-button').on('click', function (e) { console.log('clicked'); });
            $('a').on('click', function (e) {
                alert();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                debugger;
                var obj = $(this);
            });
        }

        var cx = 'my-gcse-id';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();


</script>

<gcse:search linktarget="_parent" enableAutoComplete="true"></gcse:search>
```

The above gives me the console logs on clicking the input search box and button, but not on clicking a link from the search results.
I have also tried window.load and document.ready but could not get that working.

```
<script>
    $(window).on("load", function () {

        $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background', '');
        $('#gsc-i-id1').on("blur", function (e) {

            $(this).css('background', '');
        });
        $("a").on("click", function (e) {
            alert();
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            var obj = $(this);
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background', '');
        $("a").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            var obj = $(this);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Anyone of you experts please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just worked for me ,,,!! all you need to do is add the call to alert() on a.clicked
which means in your code find the below snippet

```
$(window).on("load", function () {

    $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background', '');
    $('#gsc-i-id1').on("blur", function (e) {

        $(this).css('background', '');
    });
    $("a").on("click", function (e) {
        alert();
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        var obj = $(this);
    });
});
```

and replace it with

```
      $(window).on("load", function () {

        $("a").on("click", function (e) {
            alert();
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            var obj = $(this);
        });
    });
```

I must mention i m not using the default google custom search template I have made my own search box and m using the two column template, so in my case the window never goes blur ,,,I m pretty sure you must have figured this out by now though ..loll

After using ti for while i realised it works for result pages that don't have ads on it . If you have pages with ads , when u click on the ads .. the ads text is in a span, so that's why a.onclick event doesn't stop the defualt behaviour

Comment: Sorry but, what is the change that you have made? I am not able to find out. Those two statements for setting the background are just irrelevant. May be it worked for you because you are not using the default custom search template. Anyways, glad it worked for you!